# angular not able to search parameter from the search string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, ngroute

I recently start working on one application in angular.

now if i use `location.search()` in main controller (root url) than it works perfectly and give me search parameters.

**localhost:8080/app?foo=bar** 
works perfect.

But if i try to use `location.search()` in any other controller than it give me undefined object back.

**localhost:8080/app/exampleroute?foo=bar**

i don't understand why it is behaving like this.

is there i am missing any configuration.

I already enabled html5 mode.

Comment: I am baffled that `location.search()` doesn't throw an error. On my browser, I get `TypeError: location.search is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the dedicated angular service for url parsing https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: Thanks i find that if i was missing # in front of example route. so localhost:8080/app/exampleroute?foo=bar works perfect. But is there any way to remove # while using loction.saerch().